# /cygdrive path is broken

Tags: cygwin

My cygwin used to work properly before, but suddenly it starts to complain: "file does not exist" under /cygdrive/d ...

The problem looks like this: if I **cd** to that folder I can saw that file and **cat/ls afile** without any problem, but if I use something like **ls /cygdrive/d/afile** it will complain "file does not exist".

So I traced backwards on the file system, and found there's some issue with the virtual path /cygdrive

```
/cygdrive 
cd /cygdrive/
Error: Current working directory is a virtual Cygwin directory which
does not exist for a native Windows application. Can't start native
Windows application from here.
```

Seems this /cygdrive is broken, does anyone know how to fix it?

Adding more detail:

```
$grep cygdrive /etc/fstab
# none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0

$type -a cd
#cd is a shell builtin
```

Comment: The error "Can't start native Windows application from here" is confusing because that's not what you showed you were doing.  Does just `cd /cygdrive` cause this error, or were you trying to run something else?

Comment: just cd /cygdrive cause this error

Comment: Please post the result of `grep cygdrive /etc/fstab` in your question. Does this error happen in a Cygwin terminal, or DOS/Powershell?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman this error happen in cygwin terminal. where to start for debugging this kind of issue ?

Comment: Have you redefined the `cd` command? What is the output of `type -a cd`?

Comment: Unless Keith is right and you've redefined the `cd` command, this is a strange error.  You should ask on the Cygwin list, cygwin@cygwin.com.  Someone there will know the answer.

Comment: Do you really get that `#` character in the output of `type -a cd`?

Answer (score 3):

I get that error message if I do a `cd /cygdrive` and then try to execute a (non-Cygwin) Windows command. I don't get it if I just `cd /cygdrive`.

The only explanation I can think of is that you've assigned a value to the bash special variable `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Quoting the bash documentation:

> 'PROMPT_COMMAND'
>        If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before
>        the printing of each primary prompt ('$PS1').

For example:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND=cmd.exe ; cd /cygdrive
Error: Current working directory is a virtual Cygwin directory which does
not exist for a native Windows application.
Can't start native Windows application from here.

-bash: /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

move to the right directory by replacing (if you are in C drive for example)

```
 cd /cygdrive
```

by

```
cd c:/cygdrive
```

also suitable:

```
cd /c/<rest of your path>
```